# Batch file code for a vba program

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I have a vba code which works fine, but I want to create the same code as batch file which can do the same thing the vba code is doing.

I have created the code which sends all files in a folder to a specified email address and after sending delete the file.

Can anyone help me in creating the same thing with a batch file which can do the same thing.

Below is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Click()
Dim mess_body As String, StrFile As String, StrPath As String
Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem

Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'~~> Change path here
StrPath = "\Project\New folder\New folder\"

With MailOutLook
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    .To = "test@sdm.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .HTMLBody = "test"

    '~~> *.* for all files
    StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.*")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        .Attachments.Add StrPath & StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

    '.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
    .Send
End With

Kill "\Project\New folder\New folder\*.*"

MsgBox "Reports have been sent", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: This (COM Automation) cannot be accomplished with a Batch file.  A .VBS VBScript is the closest alternative. (Or JScript)

Comment: Ohh! I thought that can be done with batch command as well.

Comment: Also can you help me in changing the syntax "Kill "\Project\New folder\New folder\*.*" so that it can take the path from textbox1 and delete all files in that folder. I don't want to change the path every time from the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

U can use cell ("A1") value as folder reference.

```
Dim objFolder As Object

Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'~~> Change path here

VAR1 = Range("A1").Value
If VAR1 = False Then MsgBox "Cell is empty"
If VAR1 = False Then Exit Sub
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(VAR1)
With MailOutLook
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    .To = "test@test.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .HTMLBody = "test"

'~~> *.* for all files
StrFile = Dir(objFolder & "*.*")
```

...

```
'.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
.Send
End With
'delete files
Kill objFolder & "\*.*"
```